# Missing JRE in Eclipse in Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm trying to run eclipse on my Mac OS X. I've been doing some Android programming on Eclipse lately, and today wanted to do some development on Java. However, to my surprise, Eclipse says there's no JRE/JDK installed. I don't know how this is possible, since my android projects have worked very well so far, and even now. I've tried the following items:

- Checking java version through the Mac terminal. It says `java version "1.8.0_20"` is installed. Here's the screenshot.
  [image]
- I've checked the Java version through the Java Control Panel in System Preferences. Again, same thing:
  [image]
- I know that when there's no JRE visible in Eclipse, it can be manually entered through the "add" option under **preferences > Java > Installed JREs** in Eclipse. But although I can find the **Contents** folder in this path: ***/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/home/contents***, when I attempt to manually add this in Eclipse, the Java folder under users/library just doesn't show up. I have no idea why this is happening. Here are some screenshots, just in case:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the Java folder just doesn't show up under **Library** in the above screenshot.

- Lastly, I've also tried to hit "Search" in Eclipse (same place as "Add" in one of the screenshots above), but "Search" doesn't find anything at all.

I've gone through existing answers on SO which deal with similar problems. The only thing which I haven't done seems to be about setting a path variable, but they were all in Windows OS, so not sure if it applies in my situation.

I'd really appreciate any help on this.

---

Update 1: According to what has been pointed out so far, I tried copy-pasting the suggested path. But the error I get is: The home directory does not exist.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what has caused your problem, but I think you may be looking in the wrong `Library` folder. It looks like you are looking in `~/Library`, but my Java 8 "Installed JREs" is under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk*.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: This might seem wierd, but as you suggested, in my **Finder** menu, I clicked on **Go**, and entered **~/Library**, and the resulting window appears to be the same one which shows up in Eclipse. This window doesn't have the **Java** folder too, that's how I was able to make out the difference. But even copying the correct path into Eclipse doesn't point out the JRE.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find the JRE in a wrong Library directory as Library directory maybe present in more than one place. Just copy paste the jre path in 'jre home' input as

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/home/contents/Home/jre/
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To find where is your java installed on Mac, run the following command:

```
echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

it should return something like this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
```

append jre to the end of this path to build JRE home path:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

Comment: Thank You, but unfortunately, this didn't help. I get an error. Please see my revised question with the error.

Comment: there is no `jre/` file in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/`